# Groups and matrices

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $K$ be the additive group of $\mathbb Z\oplus \mathbb Z$. If $A = \left(\begin{array}{cc}
a & b\\
c & d
\end{array}\right)$ is an $2\times 2$ matrix where $a, b, c, d$, are in $\mathbb Z$, then $HA*=\langle(a,b), (c,d)\rangle$ is the subgroup generated by rows of matrix $A$.

1) Let $A= \left(\begin{array}{cc}
3 & 1\\
0 & 5
\end{array}\right)$. Show that $K/HA*$ has order 15.

2) Let $B= \left(\begin{array}{cc}
3 & 1\\
6 & 7
\end{array}\right)$. Show that $K/HB*$ has order 15.

3) Let $C= \left(\begin{array}{cc}
9 & 8\\
6 & 7
\end{array}\right)$. Show that $K/HC*$ has order 15.

My thinking: I can use something that restricts the quotient group but I am not sure how to do it?

Thank you for helping out.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to see how to get the second and third fom the first by using row operations. To see why the first gives an isomorphism to $\mathbb Z_3 \oplus \mathbb Z_5$ is trickier. You need to use the fact that $3$ and $5$ are relatively prime to get rid of the $1$ somehow.

Comment: I have tried but I cannot get anywhere? Can you please explain the hint

Comment: Do you see how to use row operations (which can be interpreted like a change of basis in linear algebra) to get the second two isomorphic to the first one?

Answer (score 2):

The [Smith Normal Form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith_normal_form) of your matrices is the same: $\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & 0\\
0 & 15
\end{array}\right).$ This shows that all three factor groups are isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_{15}$.